# Iterate over collection in Frida - Creating an iterator

Tags: javascript, frida

I'm hooking a Java method in Frida which looks like

```
public ABC setSomething(Collection<RandObject> things) {
  this.things = new ArrayList(things);
  return this;
}
```

In javascript, I'm able to log the `things` parameter and it prints out the RandObjects. I'm also able to do a `size()` and get the total number of elements inside.

Anything I do to try to iterate over the collection doesn't work. You can't access elements with `.get(X)` or `[X]`. I can't do an `Array.from` since Frida doesn't seem to have that available. I believe I need to create an iterator to properly do this. How can I do that?

I was messing around with trying to instantiate `Java.use("java.util.Iterator")` but am stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
var iter = things.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
  console.log(iter.next());
}
```